# How to configure media root file for multitenant app in django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am creating multitenant app in django. I have chosen "Isolated database with a shared app server" from this website - https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/isolated-database.html.
I am using django-storages with AWS S3 bucket.
**The problem** I could not figure out how to configure MediaRoot file for different database in django settings file. Is there any option in the settings file to use mediaroot with if condition.
For example, if I am using db_1 use this mediaroot_1 elseif using db_2 , then use mediaroot_2.
This is basically to charge the client as per the aws bucket usage.

settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["core.router.TenantRouter"]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'db_1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db_1.sqlite3',
    },
    'db_2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db_2.sqlite3',
    },
}
```

```
#### the below I need if statement for different database
#### I want to use bucket_1 for db_1 and so on
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
```

I tried to bring get_current_db_name() from the middleware.py into settings.py but I could not do it.
I have tried django-tenant-schemas and other similar packages but I would like to go without 3rd party packages.

######## middleware.py

```
import threading

from .utils import tenant_db_from_request

THREAD_LOCAL = threading.local()


class TenantMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        db = tenant_db_from_request(request)
        setattr(THREAD_LOCAL, "DB", db)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


def get_current_db_name():
    return getattr(THREAD_LOCAL, "DB", None)


def set_db_for_router(db):
    setattr(THREAD_LOCAL, "DB", db)
```